# Making money with bitcoins

Tags: transactions, altcoin

I heard stories of people on the Web making money with Bitcoins. I heard the term "mining", with bitcoin mining, but I don't really know how it works.

Can someone explain to me the process and what equipement I need to do this?

i just want to make a few hundred bicks/months, steady, and I know that some people deal with Bitcoins and similar virtual currencies.

Comment: If there were some magic way to make large amounts of money without effort that anyone could do, everyone would be doing it. If you have no special expertise, skills, or equipment in an area, there's no reason to expect to be successful in it.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly your question show a lack of research but anyway.

Mining Bitcoins is basically letting your GPU run so you can earn a few amount of Bitcoins each x amount of time (keeping it simple).
Mining bitcoins is no longer worth it considering the difficulty of the actual blocks, you won't make money with mining unless you have a few thousands ready to invest in mining rigs.

If you want to make money with Bitcoin, you may want to buy it from specialized websites (Coinbase, Circle, Localbitcoins) for price+1-3% and then resell it on forums for price+10-15%.

If you want to make money with mining in general, try to search which currencies are actually skyrocketing (today it's Ethereum, yesterday it was Litecoin, who knows what it will be tomorrow?) and rent mining rigs - it might be profitable but it'd still be an investment. You might lose it all.

Comment: `Mining Bitcoins is basically letting your GPU run` This is bad advice. You won't make any money GPU mining.

Answer (score 1):

You earn bitcoin just like real money. So no shortcut, just use your skills.